# How is Ostrich used for configuration?

Tags: scala, configuration, ostrich

I need a way to configure my scala application. Configgy seemed the way to go in Scala but it is deprecated https://github.com/robey/configgy#readme and now this functionality is in Ostrich.

Is there a code example on how to use Ostrich only for configuration? I'm not interested in collecting the statistics.

Comment: I wrote a replacement for `Configgy`. It's compatible with most legacy config files, akka config files and java properties. It's available at https://github.com/paradigmatic/Configrity

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd like to know the official answer as well, but nobody answered so I decided to poke around. Sorry if this answer isn't quite comprehensive.

The best example I found was in [`com.twitter.ostrich.admin.RuntimeEnvironment`](https://github.com/twitter/ostrich/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/twitter/ostrich/admin/RuntimeEnvironment.scala), especially if you look mainly at `loadConfig`.

Say you want to configure an instance of class `T`. The basic idea is as follows:

- Get a [`java.io.File`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) that contains Scala source code that evaluates to a [`com.twitter.util.Config[T]`](https://github.com/twitter/util/blob/master/util-core/src/main/scala/com/twitter/util/Config.scala).
- In order to be a valid `Config[T]` you'll need to have a `def apply(): T` method. To keep the implementation details out of the config file, you'll want to define a class in your project that extends `Config[T]`. You can also use this class to define default/required fields.
- Instantiate a new [`com.twitter.util.Eval`](https://github.com/twitter/util/blob/master/util-eval/src/main/scala/com/twitter/util/Eval.scala) instance, and call `apply(file)` to get a `Config[T]` instance.
- Call `config.validate()` to throw the proper exceptions for malformed config files.
- Call `config.apply()` to get your fully configured instance of `T`.

Here is a simple example, where I configure a new `WidgetService`:

```
class WidgetService(val port: Int)

class WidgetConfig extends com.twitter.util.Config[WidgetService] {
  var port = required[Int]
  def apply(): WidgetService = {
    new WidgetService(port)
  }
}

object MyApp extends App {
  val configFile = new java.io.File("mywidget_config.scala")
  val eval = new com.twitter.util.Eval
  val config = eval[com.twitter.util.Config[WidgetService]](configFile)
  config.validate()
  val widgetService = config()
  println(widgetService.port)
}
```

And here is `mywidget_config.scala`:

```
new WidgetConfig {
  port = 8000
}
```

Note: you may have to make modifications if you put this in a package. I did everything in the default package for brevity.

To get the dependencies to work, I added this to my SBT config:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.twitter" % "util" % "1.10.1"
```

Comment: Is it possible to write values back to the scala file? Because if it isn't easily than I would prefer the old good .properties files

Comment: Matroska: there's no built-in support to write values back to a scala file, but it's possible to write code to do it for the common case (similar to how the missingValues method in Config can introspect fields). However, if you do tricky things in your config you could lose that information (you'd read in `port = 1024 + 1` but you'd write back out `port = 1025`).