# How to use Ostrich

Tags: scala, configuration, ostrich

I have a task to collect and report some runtime statistics for my application. [Ostrich](https://github.com/twitter/ostrich) looks quite friendly in both API and feature set. But I can't find any documentation about the most of declared features. Especially it is difficult to configure stats reporting through the web interface without any understanding of configuration principles.

So my main question: is there any documentation besides the [README](https://github.com/twitter/ostrich/blob/master/README.md)?

If no, could someone give an example of the following features (all of them are from the top of README):

- load & reload per-environment configuration (there is [example on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504849/how-is-ostrich-used-for-configuration/6689421#6689421) already, but what if I want to use a classpath resource? how to define an environment? how to reload configuration?)
- report statistics into log files

Or (perfectly) give a good architectural overview of configuration in Ostrich so I can find some way to do configuration by myself.

Answer (score 2):

Ostrich config files are just regular scala classes, so if you want to load a classpath resource, you probably should create the config instance in code instead.

Here is how I load default config if -f command-line arg is not specified:

```
val runtime = RuntimeEnvironment(this, args)
val server =
  if (runtime.configFile.exists) {
    runtime.loadRuntimeConfig[Server]()
  } else {
    (new RPCServerConfig)()(runtime)
  }
```

Note that you have to 
 - create config instance 
 - then call it's apply() method 
 - then apply(runtime) on the result

You can easily extend this to load different configs depending by e.g. lift's `Props.mode`